# Applying same IAM policy on multiple IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 2 IAM roles for different lambdas, and I want them both to have the same IAM permissions.

How can I do that without duplicating the IAM policy descriptions, which is quite error prone.

What I have in the below code are 2 IAM role resources and 2 policy resources. I know that I won't be able to have a single policy they can use, but maybe I could at least put the JSON body of the policy in some reusable variable?

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda1" {
    name = "L1-LambdaRole"

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
    }
    EOF
    }


resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda2" {
    name = "L2-LambdaRole"

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
    }
    EOF
    }




resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "l1_dynamodb_policy" {
    name = "Allow_DynamoDb"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda1.id}"

    policy = <<EOF
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                    "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"

                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "${aws_dynamodb_table.audtiTable.arn}"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    EOF
    }

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "l2_dynamodb_policy" {
    name = "Allow_DynamoDb"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda2.id}"

    policy = <<EOF
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                    "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"

                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "${aws_dynamodb_table.audtiTable.arn}"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    EOF
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define policy as `customer managed policy`, which means it has its own ARN, and then you can attach it to roles using that ARN.

I'm not terribly familiar with Terraform, but this looks like it: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy_attachment.html